# Word formation process

Tags: morphology

Which word formation is applied in the following sentence?

'I want to re-gift this piece of furniture.'

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you're asking please?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: compounding,blending,inflection,backformation or conversion

Comment: "re-gift" is a compound word so it's an example of **compounding**.

Comment: This is not an example of compounding. "Re-gift" is not a compound word. "Cow-gift" or "late-gift" would be compounds. But "re-gift" or "un-gift" are not. The "re" is a mere prefix. Prefixes can be inflectional or derivational. And I think I can leave it as an exercise for the reader to find out whether this here prefix is used to inflect the verb *gift*, or to derive from it a different verb with a new meaning.